# How to use optical flow tracking in opencv to segment an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

Using [calcopticalflowpyrlk](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowpyrlk) from opencv2 to track the motion flow, of objects I picked on the first frame (green dots):

[image]

I draw line between the old points fed to `calcopticalflowpyrlk` and the ones outputed by `calcopticalflowpyrlk`

At the end I get this nice track 
[image]

---

Quoting @rotating_image [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399541/optical-flow-based-segmentation) to a similar question:

> You can measure the direction and the magnitude of the displacement
>   each pixel of interest undergoes in two successive frames to get an
>   idea of their movement pattern

---

Indeed, using previous and current spot of the tracked object, I can find the flow vector angle and magnitude.

But I still can't see how does it help me segment the image?

Should I compute the vectors of all the pixels, and those that have ~"the same"  angel and magnitude found previously are the object and everything else is the background?

Or am I missing something?

Comment: what exactly do you want to segment?

Comment: @Micka the tracked objects from the backgroud, even objects not being tracked. Not just the 3 cars that i marked with green dots.

Comment: 1. Min cut: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/min_cut_segmentation.php

2. Euclidean Cluster Extraction: http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cluster_extraction.php

Comment: @Nuzhny I used grabcut for segmentation in a previous project, I need to find how to use the motion flow to segment my images now...

Comment: If you want to segment every object in the frame then why is it necessary to use optical flow? Perhaps [DeepMask](https://github.com/facebookresearch/deepmask) is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have flow images and you want to auto track blob of flows that going to the same direction.

So what you get is sparse flow which would look like sth below

You can use opencv partition for this. The partition is like distance based clustering algorithm which is better than kmean because you dont have to enter the number k. Problem is it is subject to noise and false associations. So I`ll prefer to use it on set of flow vector which is larger than a threshold.

you can find a sample below

```
int th_distance = 18; // radius tolerance

int th2 = th_distance * th_distance; // squared radius tolerance
vector<int> labels;

int n_labels = partition(pts, labels, [th2](const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) {
    return ((lhs.x - rhs.x)*(lhs.x - rhs.x) + (lhs.y - rhs.y)*(lhs.y - rhs.y)) < th2; 
});
```

[image] -> [image]

where each color means a segmentes. You can adjust the parameter for your video

Then based on the initial clustering, use convex hull to get proper shape of each car out.

here is the sample  https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html

[image]
[image]

At last, aggregate the motion vector into final vector K and denote on the final vector K on the center of the hull.

Then concatenate the final vector K of each image to form a trajectory.